# Which Multi-language option for Wordpress is best from an SEO and Woocommerce perspective?

Tags: multisite, woocommerce-offtopic, multi-language, seo

I am wanting to set up an English and German version of a site for selling products and using content marketing.

So I will be doing key word research in both languages.  There will be a lot of overlap in keyword translation, but not always.  Meaning there will be more content in one of the languages.

Plus, Germany has a bit higher standard for the checkout process (hence https://marketpress.com/product/woocommerce-german-market/ ).  So I may need different checkouts.

It seems like multi-site is the way to go, but just wanted your advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you need true localization, like a different checkout process, different themes or product descriptions, then you should use a multisite. You can activate plugins and themes per site here.

The problem here is that almost all shopping plugins are not multisite compatible. You have to activate them per **site**, not as **network plugin**, or you won't get the required database tables.

The custom tables are also difficult to translate. This cannot be handled in a regular plugin, because that would create too deep dependencies. So you need an additional plugin to  fill the gap. Inpsyde/MarketPress, the company behind [MultilingualPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press/), has a private beta version of such a plugin. You can [contact](https://marketpress.com/contact/) them and ask for an invitation to the tester group.

*Disclosure:* I was the lead developer for MultilingualPress for more than two years, and I wrote the very first version of the compatibility plugin for WooCommerce.